# bash if empty string

Tags: bash, if-statement

Some may have found out that in Ubuntu when you install or update via terminal

you get a question similar to

> "do you with to install or remove package [Y/n]?"

when you press enter its like its the same as when you type "Y" or "y"

So i was wondering how to make that in bash 
This is what i have so far?

```
echo "question?[Y/n]"
read choose
if [ $choose ~= "Y" ] [ $choose ~= "y" ] [ $choose ~= "" ]
then 
#code
fi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Classically (meaning it will work in POSIX-ish shells other than `bash`), you'd write:

```
echo "Question? [Y/n]"
read choose
if [ "$choose" = "Y" ] || [ "$choose" = "y" ] || [ -z "$choose" ]
then 
    # code
fi
```

The quotes ensure that the test operator see an argument even if `$choose` is an empty string.

The `[[` operator seems to allow you to get away without quoting strings, but is not part of a POSIX shell.  POSIX recognizes its existence by noting:

> The following words may be recognized as reserved words on some implementations (when none of the characters are quoted), causing unspecified results:
>
> ```
> [[    ]]    function    select
> ```

If you want the shell to leave the cursor on the same line as the prompt, you can use:

```
printf "Question? [Y/n] "
```

POSIX shells recognize the `\c` escape; `bash` does not:

```
echo "Question? [Y/n] \c"
```

(There may be a way to make `bash` handle that, but `printf` is probably more portable.)

Comment: +1 for printf suggestion.  It is much neat compared to echo (personal opinion) :)

"echo -n" would print the message and leave the cursor on the same line, e.g.

echo -n "Question? [Y/n]"

Comment: @AshishKumar: Thanks.  I remembered that `bash` follows the Unix 7th Edition Bourne shell using `echo -n` after I'd posted the answer, instead of the System III, System V style of escape with `\c`. See [Bloated `echo` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290683/bloated-echo-command/3291618#3291618) for a discussion about styles of the `echo` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo -n "Question? [Y/n]"
read choose 
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "${choose:=Y}" =~ Y ]]; then
     # they said yes
else
     # they said something else
fi
```

This approach has the possible advantage that it leaves `$choose` set to Y if you examine it later.  If you prefer to be able to tell later whether they entered `Y` or just pressed enter, you can use `${choose:-Y}` instead.

If you'd rather not set `nocasematch`, you can always check explicitly for both `Y` and `y`.  Or, if you like the `nocasematch` solution but care about preserving the state of the flag, you can check and restore it:

```
shopt -q nocasematch
let not_set=$?
shopt -s nocasematch
```

...

```
if (( not_set )); then
   shopt -u nocasematch
fi
```

Comment: You could use `declare -u choose; read choose` instead of nocasematch. Nice call using a default value in the expansion.

Comment: True, but `declare -u` is a bash-4-ism, and that's not universal (Lion still has bash 3, for instance; not sure about Mountain Lion).   IMO, it's silly that it took this long since ksh had typeset -L and -U back in 1983, but there you go. :)

Answer (score 2):

See `test(1)`.

```
[ "$choose" = "Y" -o "$choose" = "y" -o "$choose" = "" ]
```

You **must** put the variable between double quotes, otherwise the expressions would produce an error with an empty variable, because their respective left sides would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

"read" reads input up to enter. So if you want just "enter" to be accepted as answer, try with "" answer. You can use [[ ]] instead of "test" command to check strings ( man test )

```
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ [[ -z "" ]] && echo yes 
yes
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ [[ -z "ABCD" ]] && echo yes 
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$
```

Here, a test for zero-length of the string.