# bash: How can I print an OK status on previous line after command exits?

Tags: bash

Consider the following script to stop and start tomcat:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shutdown tomcat and delete all the logs
echo --- Shutting down Tomcat...
sh /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh -force &> /dev/null
rm -f /opt/tomcat/logs/* &> /dev/null
echo OK

# Startup tomcat
sh /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh &> /dev/null

echo --- Starting up Tomcat...
until [ "`curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost:8080 | grep 'Coyote'`" != "" ];
do
  sleep 10
done

echo OK
```

What I'd like to be able to do is show the OK on the same line as the message stating what's going on. How can I achieve this?

Comment: where is the message stating _What's going on_?

Comment: echo --- Shutting down Tomcat...

Comment: I'd like it to change to "echo --- Shutting down Tomcat... [OK]" after complete.. not "echo --- Shutting down Tomcat...\n[OK]"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628327/how-to-show-and-update-echo-on-same-line

Answer (score 6):

```
echo -n "--- Shutting down Tomcat..."
...
echo OK
```

The `-n` suppresses the newline at the end of the echo.  Note that if the Tomcat server emits any information, it will start after the triple dot.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you should consider:

```
printf "--- Shutting down Tomcat..."
...
printf "OK\n"
```

(Although you could leave the second as `echo OK`, it seems better to be consistent.)

Comment: Also `printf '%s' "--- Shutting down Tomcat... "` (which could be more portable).

Comment: True: it is arguably better to use `printf`.  The problem with `echo` is the different ways of doing it.  System V shells used `echo "--- Shutting down Tomcat...\c"`; 7th Edition Bourne shell (actually, the `echo` binary) used the `-n`.  Different versions of `echo` do different amounts and types of interpretation of the strings it is given.  To some extent, POSIX standardized the `printf` command to avoid the problems with `echo`.  See also [Bloated `echo` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290683/bloated-echo-command).

Comment: Agreed, [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) specifically says that using `echo` with arguments is a journey down a black hole, err, bad idea. Black holes are cool, but you wouldn't want to get eaten by one.